# connection successful but 500 internal error while fetching data from sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

this is my config file. i am connecting to my localhost using port forwarding using bit-vise ssh client connection is success but while excuting query there is 500 internal server.

```
<?php
try {
    $hostname = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
    $port = 2351;
    $dbname = "otomax";
    $username = "sa";
    $pw = "root";
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname,$port;Database=$dbname","$username","$pw");   "connect";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    "Failed to get DB handle:".$e->getMessage()."\n";
    exit;
}
?>
```

Connection is Successful but 500 Internal Error While Fetching Data From Server please help me out

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$id=$_SESSION['kode'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.reseller WHERE kode='$id'";
$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
?>
```

please see this code and help me out

Comment: Anything in the error log? Any reason not to parameterize your query? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.reseller WHERE kode=?"; $query->execute(array($id));`. Also not too familiar with mssql but is `dbo.reseller` the correct syntax?

Comment: If you print out the generated $sql and run that directly in the database, is there an error or does it return the expected results?

Comment: @chris85, `dbo.reseller` is the correct syntax for schema-qualified objects in all ANSI-compliant databases.